# Why HttpURLConnection doesn't give me full content

Tags: android, http, download, httpurlconnection

I've made an application that is going to download data from youtube videos and process it to get the Video Image and Title and Video Quality but it's not giving me the full site data:

```
 public class QualityDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Void,ArrayList> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            char[] buffer = new char[128];
            String output = "";

            int a = reader.read(buffer);
            output = new String(buffer);

            while (a != -1 ){
                output += new String(buffer);
                a = reader.read(buffer);
            }
            Log.i("Status: ", output);
            ArrayList<String> Qualities = new ArrayList<String>();
            return Qualities;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and I get this output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
         <head id="head">
           <style name="www-roboto">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:norm<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html lang="en">
         <head id="head">
           <style name="www-roboto">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUSZ2oysoEQEeKwjgmXLRnTc.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/QHD8zigcbDB8aPfIoaupKOvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:500;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/OLffGBTaF0XFOW1gnuHF0SwlidHJgAgmTjOEEzwu1L8.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/W4wDsBUluyw0tK3tykhXEXYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.ttf)format('truetype');}</style><script name="www-roboto">if (document.fonts && document.fonts.load) {document.fonts.load("400 10pt Roboto", "E");document.fonts.load("500 10pt Roboto", "E");}</script>
             <script>var ytcsi = {gt: function(n) {n = (n || '') + 'data_';return ytcsi[n] || (ytcsi[n] = {tick: {},info: {}});},now: window.performance && window.performance.timing &&window.performance.now ? function() {return window.performance.timing.navigationStart + window.performance.now();} : function() {return (new Date()).getTime();},tick: function(l, t, n) {ticks = ytcsi.gt(n).tick;var v = t || ytcsi.now();if (ticks[l]) {ticks['_' + l] = (ticks['_' + l] || [ticks[l]]);ticks['_' + l].push(v);}ticks[l] = v;},info: function(k, v, n) {ytcsi.gt(n).info[k] = v;},setStart: function(s, t, n) {ytcsi.info('yt_sts', s, n);ytcsi.tick('_start', t, n);}};(function(w, d) {ytcsi.setStart('dhs', w.performance ? w.performance.timing.responseStart : null);var isPrerender = (d.visibilityState || d.webkitVisibilityState) == 'prerender';var vName = d.webkitVisibilityState ? 'webkitvisibilitychange' : 'visibilitychange';if (isPrerender) {ytcsi.info('prerender', 1);var startTick = function() {ytcsi.setStart('dhs');d.removeEventListener(vName, startTick);};d.addEventListener(vName, startTick, false);}if (d.addEventListener) {d.addEventListener(vName, function() {ytcsi.tick('vc');}, false);}w.__ytRIL = function(el) {if (!el.getAttribute('data-thumb')) {el.loadTime = ytcsi.now();}};})(window, document);</script>
           <script>if (window.ytcsi) {window.ytcsi.tick("_start", null, 'initpb');}</script>
           <script>if (window.ytcsi) {window.ytcsi.tick("_start", null, 'blz_watch_ads');}</script>
           <script>if (window.ytcsi) {window.ytcsi.tick("_start", null, 'blz_home_ads');}</script>
           <script>if (window.ytcsi) {window.ytcsi.tick("_start", null, 'blz_search_ads');}</script>

           <script type="text/javascript">
             var bootstrap_data = true;
           </script>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=medium-dpi">

         <link rel="icon" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/favicon-vflz7uhzw.ico" type="image/x-icon">
         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/favicon-vflz7uhzw.ico" type="image/x-icon">   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/mobile/img/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed-vflwq-hLZ.png" sizes="144x144">
         <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/mobile/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed-vflLGbwkc.png" sizes="114x114">
         <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/mobile/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed-vflNiFbcD.png" sizes="72x72">
         <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/mobile/img/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed-vflKsw8eJ.png">
         <title>YouTube</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/mobile-nirvana-tablet-mangled-vfloxt1qd.css" id="page_css">

         </head>
         <body id="body" class="atom fusion-tn">

         <div id="player"></div>
         <div id="guide-layout-cont
```

And this is not the full content that I want, 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: The output to LogCat is truncated automatically. Do something else (e.g., write it to a file, examine it in a debugger, load it in to a `WebView`). Beyond that, please use `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation, and consider using a larger buffer than 128 characters (e.g., 8192).

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how you would do it ?